# Swapping Data in excel VBA userform

Tags: vba, excel

***TL-DR; i need a way to call a variable name. So instead of calling TB_Name1_R1 i can call TB_Name1_R[i] (or whatever its called in VBA)***

I am right now working with multiple userforms in excel with VBA.

The setup is as such: I have a main window with a lot of textboxes for input of data by the user. They are all in rows called `TB_Name1_R1`, `TB_Name2_R1` .. next row is `TB_Name1_R2`, `TB_Name2_R2`.. and so forth.

A second userform for swapping holds 2 dropdown boxes with lists of the rows, so you can choose lets just say row 1 and 2, and then the idea is that you can swap the data in the two rows. So the userform calls

```
Private Sub CB1_Click()

Dim Ra As Integer
Dim Rb As Integer

Ra = RowA.ListIndex
Rb = RowB.ListIndex

If Ra = -1 Or Ra = 10 Or Ra = 15 Or Rb = -1 Or Rb = 10 Or Rb = 15 Then
    MsgBox "Wrong input, please redo", , "Wrong Input"
Else
    Call Module1.Move(Ra, Rb)

    Me.Hide
End If

End Sub
```

All of that works fine.

NOW my problem is as follow. How do i smartest create some code where the called sub use the information sendt to swap the data between the rows chosen?

The only thing i can come up with (and yes it is so very basic) is a hole lot of

```
if a = 1 then
holder1 = TB_Name1_R1
holder2 = TB_Name2_R1

if a = 2 then
holder1 = TB_Name1_R2
holder2 = TB_Name2_R2
```

And that simply cannot be the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a mix between OLdUgly's answers and some Internet research, i found the right code to be:

```
Sub Move(R1, R2)

Dim Name As String
Dim Number As Integer
Dim NN As Variant

Name = "TB_Name_R"
Number = R1

NN = Name & Number

Dim Holder1 As Variant

Holder1 = Main.Controls(NN).Value

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Something similar to the following could replace your last code snippet ...

```
holder1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Shapes("TB_R" & a & "_Name1")
holder2 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Shapes("TB_R" & a & "_Name2")
```

Where, of course, you would need to replace "Sheet1" with the appropriate worksheet name.

---

**Updated based on feedback**

This should work, and provide access to the `.Text` and `.Value` fields.

```
Dim holder1 as Control, holder2 as Control
holder1 = UserForm1.Controls("TB_R" & a & "_Name1")
holder2 = UserForm1.Controls("TB_R" & a & "_Name2")
```

Where UserForm1 is replaced with your Form.

Comment: Yeah that could be a solution, i will look into it.

Comment: But the text is input into a userform, not a worksheet?

Comment: Sorry - I misunderstood your original post. I thought the text boxes were on the worksheet.

Comment: Updated based on above comments.